# Performance of DynamoDB with single item

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB setup with a single item, so there is only one partition. How does the `rcu/wcu` be divided? Since I have a single partition, will all the rcu and wcu be used by the one partition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No of partitions doesn't just depend upon the size(1 partition for 10GB), it also depends on the provisioned rcu and wcu.
If you provision 1000 rcu , 1000 wcu , it will use 2 partitions (1000rcu/3000 + 1000wcu/1000) Then, each partition will get half of RCU and half of WCU which is 500rcu and 500wcu per partition.

and yes, if there is only one partition entire rcu and wcu will be used by that partition.

But with [Adaptive Capacity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-partition-key-design.html#bp-partition-key-partitions-adaptive), unused rcu/wcu will be distributed to hot partitions, with which we don't have to worry about hot partitioning unless we endup consuming more than provisioned.